# Dynamic 2D array in C not reading first element

Tags: c

My uni tasked me with writing a program that reads the input and stores it into a dynamic 2D array, but we haven't covered that topic. I'm encountering a problem with my implementation, as it is skipping the first character in each line. I know the code is not top quality, but I just can't figure out why it skips the first char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


#define MULT 3
#define DIV 2

char *read_line(int *col_size, int *max_c) {
    char *line = NULL;
    int size = *col_size;
    int i, c;
    line = malloc(size * sizeof *line);
    for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF); ++i) {
        if (i == size) {
            size = 1 + size * MULT / DIV;
            line = realloc(line, size * sizeof *line);
            assert(line != NULL);
        }
        line[i] = c;
    }
    if (i > *max_c)
        *max_c = i;
    if (size > *col_size)
        *col_size = size;
    return line;
}

char **read(int *row, int *col) {
    char **input = NULL;
    int row_size = 0;
    int col_size = 0;
    int i, c;
    int max_c = 0;

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        if (i == row_size) {
            row_size = 1 + row_size * MULT / DIV;
            input = realloc(input, row_size * sizeof *input);
            assert(input != NULL);
        }
        input[i] = read_line(&col_size, &max_c);
    }
    *row = i;
    *col = max_c;
    return input;
}


int main(void) {
    int row_size, col_size, i, j;
    char **board = read(&row_size, &col_size);
    for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < col_size; ++j)
            putchar(board[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    free(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've really only glanced at your code, but the one thing jumps out is you have ++i, not i++ in your for loops.

Comment: @whoasked It doesn't matter which one is used because that statement's value doesn't matter. It's not uncommon to use ++i because it may be slightly more efficient on some systems, depending on optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
> ```

in `read()` eats up the first character of a line before `read_line()` gets to see it. You'll have to find some other way to check for `EOF`. For example with

```
for (i = 0; !feof(stdin); ++i) {
```

---

Also, you don't zero-terminate your strings. Change your reading loop to

```
char *read_line(int *col_size, int *max_c) {
    int size = *col_size ? *col_size : 1;  // at least 1 for the terminating 0
    char *line = malloc(size * sizeof *line);

    if(!line)
        return NULL;

    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF); ++i) {
        if(i == size) {
            size = 2 + size * MULT / DIV;  // note the 2
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
```

to do so.

---

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i) {
>   for (j = 0; j < col_size; ++j)
>       putchar(board[i][j]);  // accesses memory that isn't yours
>   putchar('\n');             // if not all rows are of the same length.
> }
> ```

To avoid reading memory out-of-bounds, change that to

```
for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; board[i][j] != '\0'; ++j)
        putchar(board[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

since you now have zero-terminated strings. Or why not just use `puts()`?

```
for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i)
    puts(board[i]);
```

---

> ```
> free(board);
> ```

That won't deallocate the memory you allocated for the rows. You'd have to

```
for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i)
    free(bard[i]);
free(board);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see there's a lot I have to learn yet ;)))

Comment: Altough, it's possible that the program is going to try to place the '\0' at an index that isn't allocated, since it's outside the loop that checks wether i is small enough.

Comment: @guben You are right. `size = 1 + size * MULT / DIV;` should be `size = 2 + size * MULT / DIV;` Where does that idea of `MULT / DIV` come from?

Comment: From the example code given by my uni professor, who said that usually, it's multiplied by 2, but here it's better to multiply by 3/2. He didn't tell us why though xD

Comment: Actually, Valgrind throws an invalid write error, when given an empty row :/

Comment: @guben Without seeing code its hard to say something about that. Have you made sure that `size` is always `>= 1` in `read_line()`?

Comment: No, isn't there a way to do it without a special case? The code is the same, but with the changes you've recommended.

Comment: @guben isn't there a way to do it without a special case?* – Without the conditional assignment to `size` in `read_line()`? Sure, set `col_size = 1` in `read()`. (and make sure you never ever call `read_line()` with `0` as the first parameter)

Comment: Ok, I'm actually going to skip empty lines, so it's fine. Thank you for everything!